# I want to use Git in console and Intellij as my

Tags: java, eclipse, git, intellij-idea

I want to work with Intellij but without it's git plugin. 
I worked with eclipse + git in console and never had a problem. Just push/pull/commit/add etc. and opened the files with eclipse. 
Now that i've switched to Intellij, i get many errors, no matter how i open/import the pulled files to Intellij.

Most of the times it look like this:

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Test.main(Test.java:18)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
```

Or even this:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\John\Desktop\Test\Program\GitFiles\GG\DC\out\production\DC\level1.txt (The system cannot find the specified path.)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
at java.io.FileReader.<init>(FileReader.java:72)
at model.Map.mapImport(Map.java:35)
at model.Map.<init>(Map.java:26)
at model.Model.initialize(Model.java:120)
at model.Model.<init>(Model.java:37)
at Test.main(Test.java:27)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
```

However, is there any way to absolutely correcly import Project Files into Intellij that have been correctly pulled via Git? 
I even have the suspicion that the Git-Plugin from Intellij migtht sabotage everything, because it notices there is Git on the folder i am working with.

I've wasted many hours on this problem, i would be tremendously happy about help!

Greetings,
John

Comment: There are 2 problems here, the project import is one, eclipse VCS support (git) is another. How did you import the project?  Can we see `Test.java`? Is there a `C:\Users\John\Desktop\Test\Program\GitFiles\GG\DC\out\production\DC\level1.txt`?

Comment: I think i have tried every possivble option to import the project. i tried Import Project (On Folder DC), that led to these errors, i tried simply Opening the Project (same problem) i even tried creating a new project with these files.  I think Test.java can't be the problem, because we are a programmer group of 5 people, and i am the only who has these problems. Yes, the file it does not find exists on the right path.  Is there a step by step import routine? Thank you for answering!

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/creating-a-project-by-importing-existing-sources.html could help

Comment: I've followed these exact steps (many times -.-) and the problem remains.

Comment: Can you share the project github or something?

Comment: I'm thankful for you offer to look through the code, but as i said, it works for the other 4 people, so it has to be a configuration/import problem. The lines which cause the errors to be thrown are just about importing a txt file, which is where the compiler thinks it is.

Comment: Based on the "out" in the path, I think the issue is the ["output" path of intelliJ](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/configuring-module-compiler-output.html) but I can't be sure.

Comment: That finally did it. i have played around before with the outputpath settings, but there is one configuration i had missed: 
1. Project Settings - Project - Output path (choose EXTERNAL output, wherever you want) 


2.Project Settings - Modules - Paths - Inherit project compile output path.

anyways: THANK YOU for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That finally did it. i have played around before with the outputpath settings, but there is one configuration i had missed:

---

**1. Project Settings -** Project - Output path (choose EXTERNAL output ( not into Project files itself), wherever else you want)
 **2.Project Settings -** Modules - Paths - Inherit project compile output path.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use Git inside IntelliJ you should disable it. Go to Configure (In welcome menu)  > Plugins > Git Integration , and deselect it. [Looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/umBR9.jpg)

Hope it helped you.

Comment: well it did resolve the popups about Git, thank you for that.